# Don't understand gcc that well, but I can't find why it's not working

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to compile a simple "hello world"

file_name

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main () {
    printf ("Hello World\n");
}
```

then I try: gcc file_name and I get "File not recognized. File format not recognized"

I however am 100% sure I did the exact same thing a few weeks back (just to see if it works, as now) and it worked, so I just don't get it.

```
gcc -ver // returns 4.6.1 if this helpes
```

Also how is gcc -o supposed to work ? The manual (man gcc) is just gibberish at times (for me)

Comment: Try renaming your file to "file_name.cpp" (note the ending .cpp for C++ or .c for C)

Comment: You probably don't have a correct file ending (like `file.c`)

Comment: Ohhh. I am so new to ubuntu that I have no idea how file extensions work. I noticed I could put any extension I wanted on any file and I just thought they didn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc tries to guess the language used (e.g. C or C++) based on the extension of the file, so you need to ensure you have the proper file extension (usually .cpp for C++ and .c for C dource files).  Alternatively, read the manual if there is a command line option to explicitly state the format (regardless of the extension).

As for the "-o" command line parameter: the name specified after that option is the name of the object file created from the compiled source file.  The object files are then linked together to form an executable

Comment: Thank you, as I already stated, I have no idea how extensions work in unix / ubuntu. I thought gcc == c and g++ == c++. So again I thought extensions mattered not.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you program is saved as helloworld.c. Typing gcc -o myprog helloworld.c would compile helloworld.c into myprog. That way, when you want to run the program, all you type in the command line is ./myprog